# OpenCV numpy matrix frame is filled with zeroes

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv, opencv3.0

I recently downloaded openCV 3.4.5 on windows, with Python 3.5.4.

I ran this basic piece of code to show video:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    print(frame)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

A video is shown from my laptop's webcam. 
Notice that I print each frame from the video, but in my console output, every numpy array is filled with zeroes. I don't understand why it's that way, since the video is working

example console output

```
[[[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 ...
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. I suspect there's some issue with versioning or webcam access here. Can you update to OpenCV 4?

Comment: Use `histogram` to make sure it's all 0, https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/db7/tutorial_py_histogram_begins.html

Comment: Maybe take the lens cap off?

Comment: @tel there's no lens, my webcam works. OpenCV opens a window and I can clearly see my face

Comment: My apologies for the stupid joke, I couldn't resist. My actual point though is that the empty array implies that the read of that particular frame of the video failed, which can happen in a few different ways.

Comment: no worries lol. But the thing is, every matrix is only filled with zeroes, but the video recording works. Could it be a problem with the installation of a dependency, or is my version of OpenCV broken @weliketocode ? I followed this [tutorial](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2016/09/17/install-opencv-3-with-python-3-on-windows/) to set it up

Comment: It's fundamentally nonsensical. Either your `frame` arrays aren't really empty, or the images that `imshow` is displaying are all black. There isn't really a third possibility. There's no hardware issue that could cause `frame` to magically fill inbetween the call to `print` and the call to `imshow`. To prove this to yourself, you could try moving the line with the `print` statement beneath the line with `imshow`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Opencv docs](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-read), the `read` method of `VideoCapture` returns a tuple of `(ret, frame)`. `frame` will be `True` if the read of that `frame` succeeded, and `False` otherwise. Thus, in order for you to clarify what's going on when you run your code, here's what you should do:

- change the print statement in the `while` loop to `print(ret)` then run your code again

  - if the `ret` values are mostly or entirely `True`, then the reading in of each `frame` is generally succeeding. This means that the `frame` arrays aren't actually empty, they just appear that way in your printout for some reason (eg all of the values on the edges are `0`, but there are nonzero values in the part that's getting elided by the dots `...`). If you then change the print statement to `print(frame.sum())`, you should be able to easily see that there are at least some nonzero values in each `frame`
  - if the `ret` values are mostly `False`, then it means that the reading in of most `Frame`s is failing, which in turn means that empty arrays are the expected value. If `imshow` really is still displaying images in this case, that means that something truly, truly strange is happening.

Comment: hmm, all the `print(ret)` return `True` and `frame.sum()` returns non zero values, so it does indeed work. My webcam is weird I guess. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I understand that the matrices come in 3, one for each RGB channel, but do you know why each matrix has 3 columns, as shown in the console output? @tel

Comment: Notice how the printout of the array starts with three square brackets `[[[`? That implies that `frame` is a 3D array. The standard shape for a color image array is `(M, N, 3)`, where `M` is the height in pixels and `N` is the width. Imagine that you were looking straight on at one of the short sides of such an array. That's exactly what you see in the printout. The other two dimensions (which are typically much larger) get "summarized" (ie truncated). Given ~30 `frame` a second, if each was printed out in whole it would flood your output, and your computer would grind to a halt.

Comment: As for why the last dimension has a size of `3`, you can think of `frame` as a stack of three 2D arrays of shape `(M, N)`. There's one for each "channel" in the color (ie (**R**)ed, (**G**)reen, and (**B**)lue). Sometimes there's actually 4 channels in a single image array, in which cases the last channel is for the alpha, which sets the transparency of the corresponding pixel.

Comment: In my case, ret is ```true``` and ```frame.sum()``` is zero. And with ```cv2.imshow("window",frame)```, it is showing a black window.  How it can be resolved?